# How to repair ElasticSearch broken query?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I upgrade SSL my elasticsearch has stopped working and do not know why?

```
      $params = [
                'index' => 'vf_dev',
                'size'   => $filter["limit"],
                'from'   => $filter["skip"],
                'body'  => [
                    'query' => [
                        'bool' =>
                            $search
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

My query is like above. My error is lilke below. What am I missing?

{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:93] [bool] failed to parse field [must]"}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:93] [bool] failed to parse field [must]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:93

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr

I believe, your pattern for a boolean query is wrong.
As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) you should have either:

- filter
- must
- should
- must_not

I believe it is missing.